# Using MediaCodec to compress video

Tags: android, compression, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to use `MediaCodec` in Android to compress videos.

It looks like `MediaCodec` will give you back the raw stream. Is there a way to go from A->B (compress video with an output file at the end)?

Thanks.

Comment: Various examples: http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/, https://github.com/google/grafika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can employ the `MediaMuxer` class to store the elementary streams into a file format like `MP4`. Please refer to this [`cts` example](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/cts/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java#doExtractDecodeEditEncodeMux) for a good illustration of transcode + muxing where the encoded data is written into a file through the `MediaMuxer`.

Comment: Sir, Can you please take a look at this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723393/video-rendering-is-broken-mediacodec-h-264-stream