# Video rendering is broken MediaCodec H.264 stream

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec, textureview

I am implementing a decoder using `MediaCodec` Java API for decoding live H.264 remote stream. I am receiving H.264 encoded data from native layer using a callback (`void OnRecvEncodedData(byte[] encodedData)`), decode and render on `Surface` of `TextureView`. My implementation is completed (retrieving encoded streams using callback, decode and rendering etc). Here is my decoder class:

```
public class MediaCodecDecoder extends Thread implements MyFrameAvailableListener {

    private static final boolean VERBOSE = true;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MediaCodecDecoder.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String VIDEO_FORMAT = "video/avc"; // h.264
    private static final long mTimeoutUs = 10000l;

    private MediaCodec mMediaCodec;
    Surface mSurface;
    volatile boolean m_bConfigured;
    volatile boolean m_bRunning;
    long startMs;

    public MediaCodecDecoder() {
        JniWrapper.SetFrameAvailableListener(this);
    }

    // this is my callback where I am receiving encoded streams from native layer 
    @Override
    public void OnRecvEncodedData(byte[] encodedData) {
        if(!m_bConfigured && bKeyFrame(encodedData)) {
            Configure(mSurface, 240, 320, encodedData);
        }
        if(m_bConfigured) {
            decodeData(encodedData);
        }
    }

    public void SetSurface(Surface surface) {
        if (mSurface == null) {
            mSurface = surface;
        }
    }

    public void Start() {
        if(m_bRunning)
            return;
        m_bRunning = true;
        start();
    }

    public void Stop() {
        if(!m_bRunning)
            return;
        m_bRunning = false;
        mMediaCodec.stop();
        mMediaCodec.release();
    }

    private void Configure(Surface surface, int width, int height, byte[] csd0) {
        if (m_bConfigured) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Decoder is already configured");
            return;
        }
        if (mSurface == null) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Surface is not available/set yet.");
            return;
        }
        MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(VIDEO_FORMAT, width, height);
        format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap(csd0));
        try {
            mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(VIDEO_FORMAT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Failed to create codec: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mMediaCodec.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Decoder configured.");

        mMediaCodec.start();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Decoder initialized.");

        m_bConfigured = true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void decodeData(byte[] data) {
        if (!m_bConfigured) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Decoder is not configured yet.");
            return;
        }
        int inIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(mTimeoutUs);
        if (inIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer buffer;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                buffer = mMediaCodec.getInputBuffers()[inIndex];
                buffer.clear();
            } else {
                buffer = mMediaCodec.getInputBuffer(inIndex);
            }
            if (buffer != null) {
                buffer.put(data);
                long presentationTimeUs = System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs;
                mMediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, data.length, presentationTimeUs, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean bKeyFrame(byte[] frameData) {
        return ( ( (frameData[4] & 0xFF) & 0x0F) == 0x07);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            while(m_bRunning) {
                if(m_bConfigured) {
                    int outIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, mTimeoutUs);
                    if(outIndex >= 0) {
                        mMediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is - the streams is being decoded and rendered on surface but the video is not clear. It seems like the frames are broken and scene is distorted/dirty. The movement is broken and square shaped fragments everywhere (I am really sorry as I don't have the screenshot right now).

About my streams - its H.264 encoded and consists of I frames and P frames only (there is no B frame). Every I frame has `SPS + PPS + payload` structure. The color format used during encoding (using FFMPEG in native layer) is YUV420 planner. The sent length of data from native layer is okay (width * height * (3 / 2)).

During `configure()` I just set the `csd-0` value with SPS frame. The frame used for configuration was an I frame (SPS + PPS + payload) - the prefix was a SPS frame, so I think the configuration was successful. Note that, I didn't set the `csd-1` value with PPS frame (is it a problem?).

Every frame has preceding start codes (`0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01`) for both p-frame and I-frame (for I-frame the start code is present both infront of SPS and PPS frame).

Moreover, I am setting the presentation timestamp as `System.currrentTimeMillis() - startTime` for every frame which is increasing order for every new frame. I think this shouldn't cause any problem (Correct me if I am wrong).

My device is Nexus 5 from Google with Android version 4.4.4 and chipset is Qualcomm MSM8974 Snapdragon 800. I am using `Surface` for decoding, so I think there should not be any device specific color format mismatch issues.

I can also provide my `TextureView` code if needed.

What might be the cause of my incorrect decoding/rendering? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**

I tried by manually passing my codec-specific data(SPS and PPS bytes) during configuration. But this didn't make any change :(

```
byte[] sps  = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x67, 0x4d, 0x40, 0x0c, (byte) 0xda, 0x0f, 0x0a, 0x68, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, (byte) 0xa3, (byte) 0xc5, 0x0a, (byte) 0xa8};
format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap(sps));

byte[] pps = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x68, (byte) 0xef, 0x04, (byte) 0xf2, 0x00, 0x00};
format.setByteBuffer("csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap(pps));
```

I also tried by trimming the start codes (`0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01`) but no progress!

**EDIT 2**

I tried with hardware accelerated {{TextureView}} as it is mentioned in [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) (though I didn't find any H/W acceleration code in sample project of MediaCodec-textureView). But still no progress. Now I commented the H/W acceleration code snippet.

**EDIT 3**

The screenshots are avilable now:

[image: broken decoded H264 video MediaCodec]
[image]

**EDIT 4**

For further clarification, this is my H.264 encoded I-frame hex stream format:

> 00 00 00 01 67 4d 40 0c da 0f 0a 68 40 00 00 03 00 40 00 00 07 a3 c5
>   0a a8 00 00 00 01 68 ef 04 f2 00 00 01 06 05 ff ff 69 dc 45 e9 bd e6
>   d9 48 b7 96 2c d8 20 d9 23 ee ef 78 32 36 34 20 2d 20 63 6f 72 65 20
>   31 34 36 20 2d 20 48 2e 32 36 34 2f 4d 50 45 47 2d 34 20 41 56 43 20
>   63 6f 64 65 63 20 2d 20 43 6f 70 79 6c 65 66 74 20 32 30 30 33 2d 32
>   30 31 35 20 2d 20 68 74 74 70 3a 2f 2f 77 77 77 2e 76 69 64 65 6f 6c
>   61 6e 2e 6f 72 67 2f 78 32 36 34 2e 68 74 6d 6c 20 2d 20 6f 70 74 69
>   6f 6e 73 3a 20 63 61 62 61 63 3d 31 20 72 65 66 3d 31 20 64 65 62 6c
>   6f 63 6b 3d 31 3a 30 3a 30 20 61 6e 61 6c 79 73 65 3d 30 78 31 3a 30
>   78 31 20 6d 65 3d 68 65 78 20 73 75 62 6d 65 3d 30 20 70 73 79 3d 31
>   20 70 73 79 5f 72 64 3d 31 2e 30 30 3a 30 2e 30 30 20 6d 69 78 65 64
>   5f 72 65 66 3d 30 20 6d 65 5f 72 61 6e 67 65 3d 31 36 20 63 68 72 6f
>   6d 61 5f 6d 65 3d 31 20 74 72 65 6c 6c 69 73 3d 30 20 38 78 38 64 63
>   74

And this is a P-frame:

> 00 00 00 01 41 9a 26 22 df 76 4b b2 ef cf 57 ac 5b b6 3b 68 b9 87 b2
>   71 a5 9b 61 3c 93 47 bc 79 c5 ab 0f 87 34 f6 40 6a cd 80 03 b1 a2 c2
>   4e 08 13 cd 4e 3c 62 3e 44 0a e8 97 80 ec 81 3f 31 7c f1 29 f1 43 a0
>   c0 a9 0a 74 62 c7 62 74 da c3 94 f5 19 23 ff 4b 9c c1 69 55 54 2f 62
>   f0 5e 64 7f 18 3f 58 73 af 93 6e 92 06 fd 9f a1 1a 80 cf 86 71 24 7d
>   f7 56 2c c1 57 cf ba 05 17 77 18 f1 8b 3c 33 40 18 30 1f b0 19 23 44
>   ec 91 c4 bd 80 65 4a 46 b3 1e 53 5d 6d a3 f0 b5 50 3a 93 ba 81 71 f3
>   09 98 41 43 ba 5f a1 0d 41 a3 7b c3 fd eb 15 89 75 66 a9 ee 3a 9c 1b
>   c1 aa f8 58 10 88 0c 79 77 ff 7d 15 28 eb 12 a7 1b 76 36 aa 84 e1 3e
>   63 cf a9 a3 cf 4a 2d c2 33 18 91 30 f7 3c 9c 56 f5 4c 12 6c 4b 12 1f
>   c5 ec 5a 98 8c 12 75 eb fd 98 a4 fb 7f 80 5d 28 f9 ef 43 a4 0a ca 25
>   75 19 6b f7 14 7b 76 af e9 8f 7d 79 fa 9d 9a 63 de 1f be fa 6c 65 ba
>   5f 9d b0 b0 f4 71 cb e2 ea d6 dc c6 55 98 1b cd 55 d9 eb 9c 75 fc 9d
>   ec

I am pretty sure about my stream's correctness as I successfully rendered using `ffmpeg` decoding and `GLSurfaceview` with `OpenGLES 2.0`.

Comment: Hello Kaidul! I'm having very similar problem right now. You can see my approach (slightly different from yours) of decoding in [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739047/android-decode-raw-h264-stream-with-mediacodec). My video output seems very similar to yours. I've tried your decoder class in my project, unfortunatly with the same results. Have you made it work properly?

Comment: @KrzysztofKansy Hopefully I am not the only one to face this problem ;) No, unfortunately I couldn't solve the problem. I didn't try your code yet, but it seems we are almost indifferent. If either you or me can find the solution, both will be advantageous I hope :)

Comment: I hope so too;) As for today I was mostly tinkering with presentation timestamps, but literally nothing I tried has positive impact on my output. Have you tried to export decoded frames to file? I mean checking if they are valid after going out of the decoder and before drawing on the surface. I tried bitmap export, but without success. Well, I'm not even sure if the output buffer of the decoder can be properly exported this way. Anyway, it would be good to now that decoding goes well. Regards ;)

Comment: Hi! I updated my question, just so you know. I succeeded playing video encoded with MediaCodec with my player, so I guess there are some problems with handling the raw data to the decoder, in my case at least. I think you could try it too, in order to eliminate the possibility of bugs in player itself. Regards :)

Comment: Okay, I see. I tried by decoding only I-frames and skipping p-frames and it seems the rendering didn't broke on that case. But I can't skip p-frames eventually, so this is not a solution. Can you give me your encoder and encoded frame generating code?

Comment: The mechanics are heavily based on Grafika's ContinuousCaptureActivity, excluding CircularEncoderBuffer. Instead pushing data to that buffer I'm sending data to this class: http://pastebin.com/bj8ZR71P. Saving is done after desired number of buffers are recieved.

Comment: would it be too much troble to see all your code? I'm trying to do pretty much the same thign as you, and some decent example code would be a great starting point.

Comment: Sorry @Gala, I left the company and lost the authority to see the code anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took H.264 dump both from native layer and Java layer and found the dump of native layer was played perfectly but the Java layer's dump was played as broken as the decoded stream. The problem was - during passing encoded streams from native layer to Java, the encoded stream was not passed properly(corrupted) and it was because of my buggy implementation (sorry to who were following this thread for this inconvenience).

Moreover I was passing I-frame's payload only to decoder which resulted in broken rendering. Now I am passing complete NAL unit (SPS + PPS + payload) and everything is okay now :)

Comment: Can you explain how you go this working? I'm taking RTP and trying to depacketize for android MediaCodec and the picture comes out pretty weird, lots of strange colors and what not.. Definitely not how it should.