# Is it possible to read VES (video elementary stream) using MediaExtractor?

Tags: android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

I have a file that was encoded as ves file in h264 format.

If I try to pass this file path to `MediaExtractor`

```
AMediaExtractor *ex = AMediaExtractor_new();
auto err = AMediaExtractor_setDataSource(ex, filename.c_str());;
```

I get such error

```
/com.myapp.ar E/FileSource: seek to -5988098104769797880 failed
/com.myapp.ar E/NdkMediaExtractor: sf error code: -1010
/com.myapp.ar E/myapp: ERROR ::: -10000
```

So, as far as I understand issue is when you work with ves file you don't have a container which include important data (some headers...)

So, I am looking for way (some settings options) how to `setDataSource()` and don't get errors...

Feel free to ask

Comment: MediaExtractor is used, as you mentionned above, to extract tracks (audio, video, subtitles,...) contained in a container (a .MP4 file for example). So what you are trying to do is to extract an already/a never muxed track...why?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/q/32739047/192373